# i have add time query while fetching data but it says no data found in php

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, fetch

so i want to fetch data uploaded today only ,i have add curdate() while fetching data but it says no data found . i have uploaded data but it is not working . 
here is my php  code of fetching data. i have saved time while uploading data as `$time = date("F j, Y, h:i a");` which has output like this in database 'August 22, 2017, 07:25 pm'

```html
<?php
     require_once 'dbconfig.php';

 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT vid, session,time ,views ,name, videoname, image, url FROM video where type = "Video/Trailer" && DATE(`time`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT  8');
 $stmt->execute();
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
 {
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row);
   
   {
$play =  " single.php?vid=$vid";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should set the datatype of the column with dates to `datetime`.

Comment: how please can you explain or can show in that code@MartinHeralecký

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into trouble because you're storing your dates in a non-standard string such as: "August 22, 2017, 07:25 pm". When you try to turn it back into a date, the DB can't parse it.  Try:

```
SELECT DATE('August 22, 2017, 07:25 pm'); // will return NULL
```

If you wish to store dates as string, MySQL will expect `2017-08-22 19:25:00`

```
SELECT DATE('2017-08-22 19:25:00'); // will return 2017-08-22
```

So if you want to store your dates as string, change:

```
$time = date("F j, Y, h:i a");
```

To

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But storing dates as string has severe limitations. For one, you need to call the `DATE` function above to turn it back into a date.  It will be *much* better to store dates as the proper type (eg: `datetime`).  This will allow you to perform much faster date operations.

So change the table column type if you can, or change the string format you're using to save the dates.